# Drawing / Sketching widget that can be embedded in websites to be used as an online drawing tool

Tags: jquery, flash, html, canvas, drawing

I am looking for a non-commercial or commercial online widget/tool written either in Java, Flash, HTML5 and JAVASCRIPT or any other way, that provides the following features:

- Can be embedded inside a website (like a java applet, flash , or javascript div, ..)
- Has the primary drawing or image editing tools such as (pen, eraser, color pick , etc..)
- Has a save feature that saves the works in JPEG or PNG or other useful formats

I have searched and searched and found only http://www.mainada.net/inputdraw/ which seems to have very limited tools.

There are sites that have drawing canvases (photoshop.com or http://muro.deviantart.com/) but as far as I know its not possible to embed those and have them load / save a specific file!

Any kind of help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3):

SVG edit

https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/

Has basic shapes, line, bezier, multi-segment.  Page above has link to sandbox where you can play.

Web Tools for You to Use.

http://webtools4u2use.wikispaces.com/Drawing,+Charting+%26+Mapping+Tools

Extensive list of items, mostly not useful, but worth looking at.

Cool Tools for Schools to Use

http://cooltoolsforschools.wikispaces.com/Drawing+Tools

Another list of things to check out.  Most are too specialized and have limited capability.

http://www.jswidget.com/index-ipaint.html

This one is typical of paint programs -- you can't edit what you just drew, except with the undo key.

I would recommend starting with the SVG edit code.  Objects are kept in vector space, so re-editing is possible.

Comment: Are there any new drawing tool we can embedd in website? I can't believe that I can't find a proper one. SVG-edit is not really usable as you draw one line and it removes the drawing tool and auto select the current svg.